# Google Maps JS API - Resize ALL custom markers based on zoom level

Tags: google-maps, gmaps.js

This is a fairly common question but all answers I have found only work with a single marker, I have one example on jsfiddle in witch I place 4 markers on the map (this is just for example porpuses, in my real scenario the position for the markers comes from an API source).
I can "only" change the size for one of the markers and I do a Zoom in, and can't quite find a way to replicate it to all markers, so it there's another way around it I would appreciate some clues.

```
 /** declare map as a global variable */
var map;
      

  /** create map   */
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  
  /*  add markers to map   */

   var icon = {
          url: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx8bz4yobukzb9v/sonangol_marker.png?dl=1",
          size: new google.maps.Size(50, 58),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 28),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 28) // anchor
        }
   var places = ['33.808678', '33.808978', '33.809278', '33.809578'] 
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i], -117.918921),
        map: map,
        icon: icon
       });
    }
    
    map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
    
            //set the icon with the new size to the marker
      if (map.zoom>=20) {
             marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(50,58 );
             marker.icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(25,58);
             }
      else if (map.zoom>=16) {
             marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(40,48 );
             marker.icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(20,48);
             }
      else if (map.zoom>=13) {
             marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(30,38 );
             marker.icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(15,38);
             }
      else if (map.zoom>=7) {
             marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(20,28 );
             marker.icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(10,28);
             }
      else if (map.zoom>=5) {
             marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(10,18);
             marker.icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(5,18);
            }
      else {
             marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(5,9);
             marker.icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(2.5,9);
            }
      marker.setMap(map);
      //console.log(marker.icon);
    

      });
```

The demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/brunocerq/mer6qjfy/111/).
To check it just run the jsfiddle demo and do a Zoom in on the map.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not ( just) a link to an external site like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep references to all the markers, process through that array updating the size. If you have lots of markers, this will take a while.

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
  let scaledSize;
  let anchor;
  //set the icon with the new size to the marker
  if (map.zoom >= 20) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(50, 58);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(25, 58);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 16) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(40, 48);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(20, 48);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 13) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(30, 38);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(15, 38);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 7) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(20, 28);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(10, 28);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 5) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(10, 18);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(5, 18);
  } else {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(5, 9);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(2.5, 9);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var icon = markers[i].getIcon();
    icon.scaledSize = scaledSize;
    icon.anchor = anchor;
    markers[i].setIcon(icon);
  }
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bLt1de6f/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
/** declare map as a global variable */
var map;


/** create map   */

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

/*  add markers to map   */

var icon = {
  url: "https://irdp.bmc-hosting.com/assets/img/sonangol_marker.png",
  size: new google.maps.Size(50, 58),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 28),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 28) // anchor
}
var places = [{lat: 33.808678,lng: -117.918921},{lat: 33.808978, lng: -117.918921},{lat: 33.809278, lng: -117.918921},{lat: 33.809578, lng: -117.918921},{lat: 33.809578, lng: -117.908921},]
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i], ),
    map: map,
    icon: icon
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
  let scaledSize;
  let anchor;
  //set the icon with the new size to the marker
  if (map.zoom >= 20) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(50, 58);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(25, 58);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 16) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(40, 48);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(20, 48);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 13) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(30, 38);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(15, 38);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 7) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(20, 28);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(10, 28);
  } else if (map.zoom >= 5) {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(10, 18);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(5, 18);
  } else {
    scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(5, 9);
    anchor = new google.maps.Point(2.5, 9);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var icon = markers[i].getIcon();
    icon.scaledSize = scaledSize;
    icon.anchor = anchor;
    markers[i].setIcon(icon);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```